# Positioning text to the right

Tags: beamer, text-manipulation

I want to position text further in the right in Beamer. For example I have a first line and I want the second line to begin somewhere in the middle below the second line.

Till now I have been using the command `\,\,\,` in math mode many times but this is not really efficient. Is there some other command I can use?

Comment: We really need to see a small bit of compileable code to best assess what might be done (for example, using an `align` environment).  However, short of that, `quad` provides a bigger space than `\,` and `\qquad` even bigger.

Comment: Hi, no there is no align environment. Just "plain text".

Comment: Have you tried `\quad` and `\qquad`?

Comment: Yes, but it only works once. I need the text to go even further to the right.

Comment: Wait, did you use `$\,\,\,$` to move normal text to the right? If so, try using `\hspace*{1cm}`. That might be more convenient.

Comment: Let's see if this works

Comment: Do you want to have all following lines to be indented? Then it might be easier to put it in a box and move the box.

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot. No, I made it work both with hspace and vspace. I just was not aware of this command or how to look for it. Thanks a lot

Comment: So this is solved?

Comment: If you mean in the exact center with "somewhere in the middle", you might also have a look on `\centering` or `\begin{center}...\end{center}`

Comment: Also there is an enviroment called `tabbing` which might be more convenient if you want several lines on the same slide to be indented.

Comment: Yes, thanks a lot, all solved. I just did not know the specific command, hspace. I know about centering, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

If `\quad` and `\qquad` don't produce enough indentation, you should try `\hspace{<some length>}`, where `<some length>` would ideally be a fraction of `\textwidth`, say, `0.2\textwidth` or `0.333\textwidth`.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
some text

\quad some text

\qquad some text

\hspace{0.2\textwidth} some more text

\hspace{0.333\textwidth} still more text

\hspace{0.5\textwidth} still more text
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You forgot to show the usage of `tabbing` if you want to encapsulate all comments into this answer.

Comment: @Skillmon - Thanks for this. It actually isn't clear to me what the OP's use case is. Hence, I can't tell if a `tabbing` environment would be useful -- or, rather, overkill.